# AWS EC2: Inconsistent volume name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to automate the process of backing up some `ec2` instance volumes with ansible's respective [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/ec2_snapshot_module.html).

However, when I log in to my instance:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       59G  3.2G   55G   6% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop4       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop2       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/734
/dev/loop6       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5548
/dev/loop3       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5662
/dev/loop1       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
/dev/loop0       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1003
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1004
```

When I tried to use `/dev/xvda1` as volume name, I got an error that

> msg: Could not find volume with name /dev/xvda1 attached to instance i-02a334fgik4062

I had to explicitly use `/dev/sda1`

Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant parts of your playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not specific to ansible, the AWS EC2 API does the same thing, as specified in the [Device Name Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html#device-name-limits) section of their documentation; summarized here to avoid the "link-only" answer anti-pattern:

> Depending on the block device driver of the kernel, the device could be attached with a different name than you specified. For example, if you specify a device name of /dev/sdh, your device could be renamed /dev/xvdh or /dev/hdh. In most cases, the trailing letter remains the same. In some versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and its variants, such as CentOS), even the trailing letter could change (/dev/sda could become /dev/xvde). In these cases, the trailing letter of each device name is incremented the same number of times. For example, if /dev/sdb is renamed /dev/xvdf, then /dev/sdc is renamed /dev/xvdg. Amazon Linux creates a symbolic link for the name you specified to the renamed device. Other operating systems could behave differently.

In every case I've ever seen, the `sd` versions are specified to the AWS API, but they materialize as `xvd` (or even sometimes as `nvme`) on the actual instance